# HTML5 / Javascript authentication against JAX-RS interface

Tags: html, rest, jquery-mobile, jboss

I'm implementing a backend and a web frontend with JBoss AS 7.1 and JSF. I want to implement a mobile client with JQuery Mobile (HTML5) that calls some REST interfaces made with Jax-RS.
All interface methods need to be bound to a user that has to be logged in. How can I assure that the user is authenticated?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way would be to leverage the authentication mechanisms provided by the container, Basic Authentication being the simplest.  [Here is an example](http://aspemo.blogspot.com/2011/12/jboss-and-basic-authentication.html) showing how to do this within your application.  The primary caveat with this approach, however, is that your credentials go across the network in plaintext.  Because of that, you DEFINITELY want to implement SSL on your appserver to encrypt the data in transit.